# Powershell send e-mail with JSON body via Graph API

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I try to send an email with a JSON body via Graph API but I got HTTP 400 bad request answer.
Tried to change the contentType to Text, but that failed too.

What's the right way to embed a json content?

Thanks!

```
$content=$data | ConvertTo-Json

$URLsend = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$sender/sendMail"
$BodyJsonsend = @"
                    {
                        "message": {
                          "subject": "$subject",
                          "body": {
                            "contentType": "application/json",
                            "content": "$content"
                          },
                          
                          "toRecipients": [
                            {
                              "emailAddress": {
                                "address": "$recipient"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                          ,"attachments": [
                            {
                              "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                              "name": "$FileName",
                              "contentType": "text/plain",
                              "contentBytes": "$base64string"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "saveToSentItems": "false"
                      }
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URLsend -Headers $headers -Body $BodyJsonsend
```

Comment: You are missing the From and Sender which are required.  You format does not match the following webpage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#methods

Comment: the $sender is in the $URLsend variable. The issue is not that, it can send email. My problem is that it cannot send if it the body content is JSON.

Comment: You're not showing what is in $content. Perhaps you need append switch `-Depth`  to the `ConvertTo-Json` line with a higher value than the default value of 2 ?. (the Depth value can be any number from 0 to 100)

Answer (score 0):

Below is something that I followed, which gave me the expected results.

For demonstration purposes, I have used the below Json for my content.

```
[{
    "name": "Project1",
    "description": "ABCD",
    "Last updatetime": "2022-04-11T03:29:25Z"
}, {
    "name": "Project2",
    "description": "EFGH",
    "Last updatetime": "2022-07-21T03:29:25Z"
}, {
    "name": "Project3",
    "description": "IJKL",
    "Last updatetime": "2022-11-10T03:29:25Z"
}]
```

Below is the complete script that worked for me I used to send the mail

```
$result = Get-Content result.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$BodyJsonsend = @{                                             
    "message"= @{
        "subject"= "Sample"
        "body"= @{
            "contentType"= "Text"
            "content"= $result
        }
        "toRecipients"=@(
        @{
            "emailAddress"= @{
                "email"= "<Your_Email_Id>"
                "name"= "<Name>"
            }
        }
        )
        "attachments"= @(
        @{
            "@odata.type"= "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"
            "name"= "$FileName"
            "contentType"= "application/json"
            "contentBytes"= "$base64string"
        }
        )
    }
 } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

$BodyJsonsend
```

[image]